# Touch drag-and-drop positioning near tap with JS

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, touch

I want to make function to drag and drop some elements on my page. When I use code below, the element moves by touch, but it is not staying near finger where I tapped (for expample in the center or left/right bottom of the element), but it moves to right bottom from the finger. What I want - is to be able to move element dragging it by point where I tapped.

```
function touchStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var whichArt = e.target;
    resetZ();
    whichArt.style.zIndex = 10;
}

function touchMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dragElem = e.target;
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var positionX = touch.pageX;
    var positionY = touch.pageY;
    dragElem.style.left = positionX + 'px';
    dragElem.style.top = positionY + 'px';
}

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);

<!--elements I want to drag-->
<img draggable="true" id="one" src="images/one.svg" style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 120px; z-index: 3;">
<img draggable="true" id="two" src="images/two.svg" style="position: absolute; left: 367px; top: 150px; z-index: 3;">
```

I also tried to different things to calculate left and right position, but it failed, for example:

```
var moveOffsetX = dragElem.offsetLeft - touch.pageX;
var moveOffsetY = dragElem.offsetTop - touch.pageY;
var positionX = touch.pageX - moveOffsetX; /* + also tried*/
var positionY = touch.pageY - moveOffsetY; /* + also tried*/
```

So how is it possible to accomplish the right behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because the anchor point of the element is on the top left corner.

Try this in your `touchMove` function:

```
dragElem.style.left = positionX - dragElem.width / 2 + 'px';
dragElem.style.top = positionY - dragElem.height / 2 + 'px';
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/hme3u02z/0/). You can test it on chrome using the device mode in the developer tools.

PS. you should have a `touchend` event to re-initialize the `z-index` (if you did not already do that).

**Edit**

So, in the `touchstart` event , you must save the anchor of the element (where the user touched the element).

To do so, you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` function. It's better than to depend on the style, top/left attributes because they may not be specified :

```
var elementRect = whichArt.getBoundingClientRect();
anchor = {
    top: touch.pageY - elementRect.top,
    left: touch.pageX - elementRect.left
 };
```

And then you use this `anchor` to compute top/left instead of the center of the element (as I thought at first).

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/hme3u02z/)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly what I needed, this centralizes the tap point. The question was how to move by point where I dragged. For example, when the element is big rectangle, how can I drag it by left bottom corner because it can be more comfortable to do it like this. http://interactjs.io/ - first dragging example - is what I need but I can't really understand how it works there.